# Unable to update imagefile column in Parse using Swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform, ios9, xcode7.3

I am selecting a cell in table view, passing value to view controller and then allow user to update the row on Parse (running on Heroku) using below code.

Issue i am facing is -  "title" column is updated but imagefile column doesnt get updated with new image selected. I can see that new image is indeed passed into the code.

I am using synchronous call because dont want user to move ahead unless record is saved.

what could be wrong? Same code to save a new object works fine.

Thanks 
Ashish

```
                let query = PFQuery(className:"class")
                query.whereKey("objectId", containsString: passedObject.objectId)

                do {

                    let results = try query.findObjects() 

                    if results.count == 0 {

                         print("error")

                        success = false

                     } else {
                        //update


                        do {

                            let obj = results.first

                            obj!["title"] = Title.text!

                            let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageOutlet.image!,0.2)
                            let imageFile = PFFile(name: "image.png", data: imageData!)


                            //try imageFile?.save() // is this needed?
                            obj!["imagefile"] = imageFile

                            try obj!.save()
                            self.success = true 


                        }  catch let er as NSError {

                            print(" error while updating - \(er)")
                        }

                     }
                } catch {

                    print("error while querying  \(error)")

                    success = false
                }
```

Comment: Can you please execute the save() function on the file and see if you get results? Also i noticed that you are executing sync call to the server this is something that will stuck your main thread, you can execute this on the background thread by calling saveInBackground and not save

Comment: I did run save() on file but that didn't work too. I am making sync call deliberately as I am using unwind segue so if i use saveInBackground then thread will return before saving completes which i don't want.

Comment: Can you please paste the code of your imageOutlet definition?

Comment: @IBOutlet weak var imageOutlet: UIImageView!

Comment: Hi , can you please do the following:
let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageOutlet.image,0.2)
                            let imageFile = PFFile(name: "image.png", data: imageData)

just remove the ! in both lines

Comment: XCode asks to add '!' to bot the lines. Same code works when saving new row however !!!

Comment: So the file is being saved but you get warning from xcode ?

Comment: Not a warning. Get error. So can't build.

Comment: ok, i tested in on my side and posted an answer. I did a very simple project with imageView and then created a PFFile out of it and it works. Please follow the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran some tests on my side and this code works for me:

**Aync Version**

```
    let query = PFQuery(className: "FileTest")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.imageOutlet.image!, 0.2)
        let fileToSave = PFFile(name: "myfile.png", data: imageData!)

        let firstObj = objects?.first
        firstObj!["fileToSave"] = fileToSave
        firstObj!.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            print("Object has been saved.")
        }


    }
```

**Sync Version**

```
    let query = PFQuery(className: "FileTest")

    do {
        let objects = try query.findObjects()
        let firstObj = objects.first

        let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.imageOutlet.image!, 0.2)
        let fileToSave = PFFile(name: "myfile.png", data: imageData!)
        firstObj!["fileToSave2"] = fileToSave
        try firstObj!.save()
        print("object saved")


    } catch let er as NSError {
        print("error")
    }
```

Comment: You are creating new object. Try saving a new file for this object id.

Comment: Save a new file for an existing object ?

Comment: I updated my answer. I first fetch all objects and then update the file for the first object in the result and save it. It works for me as expected ..

Comment: Yes. My code is failing when i try to save the object with different image. I tried your code with contenttype parameter but still same issue. New image is not saved. i can see new URL generated by PFFile() method call but somehow obj!.save() ignores it. Could this be a bug?

Comment: Hi Ran, as i have mentioned in comment, i don't want to use background save as i want user to wait till success and if i use background save then my segue runs to calling VC and may give wrong status to user. Thas is why i use sync call query.findObjects()

Comment: Hi Ram, I have solved it. I don't whether it is a bug - column name in Parse is imageFile and  file variable in my code is "imagefile". I changed this variable name to "fileToSave" and now i am able to update the object on Parse !!!! Strangely this doesn't give problem when adding !! Thank you for taking time out to help. I will upvote your answer.